# Disable scientific notation and offset in pandas .plot() function

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scientific-notation

I have a dataframe df with 2 columns I want to plot together and days as index:

```
           | col1  | col2   | col3 | ...
2020-01-01 | 1     | 300000 | ...
2020-01-02 | 1000  | 600000 | ...
2020-01-03 | 3000  | 50000  | ...
```

Plotting col1 + col2 via

```
df[["col1", "col2"]].plot()
```

shows values from 0 till 1.0 and at the top "1e6" like in this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJjgX.png

I want the full value range on the y-axis and no scientific notation. How can I do this via pandas .plot() or matplotlib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options:

**Option One:** With Matplotlib

```
axes=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
axes.set_xticks() # with list or range() inside
axes.set_yticks() # with list or range() inside

#You can also label the ticks with your desired values
axes.set_xticklabels() # with list or range() inside
axes.set_yticklabels() # with list or range() inside
```

**Option Two:** Change Pandas settings

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```

or

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

I believe option one is better since you need it only for the graph and don't necessarily want to modify your dataframe columns.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can try changing the `axes.formatter.limits` property of `rcParams`:

```
plt.rcParams["axes.formatter.limits"] = (-5, 12)
```

Matplotlib uses scientific notation if log10 of the axis range is smaller than the first or larger than the second.

You can customize the lower and upper limits for desired output.

Answer (score -3):

Use `.set_ylim([min,max])` for setting the y axis limit of the plot